# jqgrid password field not only in edit mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I'm trying to implement 2 things:

1. Adding `edittype:'password'` to one of my columns so I will be able to see `***` instead of the actual value itself. The problem here is that I see `***` only when I edit the row, but when I select another row, I save the old row, and disable it from editing mode, but now when it's not an input I can see the actual value - so it's like I never used `password` input. What do I need to do in order to see the value as password also when I'm not in edit mode??
2. I want to condition the password column not to be on all rows of this column, is that possible to do? I want to check another value from the row and only if it equals a certain value I want to set the field as password, and if it's not equals to leave it as a regular field. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

1) When you select another row and change the old row to disable edit mode, replace all characters in the textbox with a '*' after saving the row.  Since it's saved you don't need to maintain the value since it's not an input anymore.

2) use jquery selectors to selectively place the password attribute based on the value of the other row, also selected using a jquery selector.  Since it seems like a grid you are working with all cells should have a unique identifier to use for selection.

The conditioning of the column would probably be easiest to set after rendering.  Without having more information about the grid layout and specifics about the columns some of this is guess work.